# Nameserver 127.0.0.53 unable to resolve domain names

Tags: dns, dnsmasq, nameserver

I know there is an easy fix to the problem by adding

`nameserver 8.8.8.8`

to /etc/resolve.conf but this is merely a hack and not a proper trouble shoot of the problem that caused the problem. If I am not wrong having the 'default'(or what do you call it ?) nameserver 127.0.0.53 should be enough on a fairly new Linux system (Ubuntu 16.04). I have gone through other related questions here and tried all those but to no avail. Some of the things I tried:

1. Connecting through different NIC ( wlan0, Eth0 )
2. configuring static IP (with google's DNS ) as well as dynamic IP ( with the default gateway [192.168.43.1] as the DNS.

But all without any success. I had some boot issues with the hard drive (my hard drive became unbootable for sometime because apparently there was some issue with bootloader which I fixed later with boot-repair).

In short, I can't ping google.com if there is nameserver 127.0.0.53 . But I can ping if I add nameserver 8.8.8.8

If anybody can help me to right direction that would be great. Thanks.

Update:

If it helps, I  actually have dual boot system with Lubuntu 18.10 as well and it doesn't have the problem.
the /etc/resolve.conf file has nameserver 127.0.0.53 .

Comment: 127.0.0.0/8 is *all* your PC. Why do you think a DNS service should be running on your PC?

Comment: If you want to avoid 'hacking' things, your DNS servers should be coming from DHCP. Check your DHCP logs. `cat /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.<name of interface>.leases`. What does the last entry say?

Comment: @Daniel, did you understand what the question is ?

Comment: @JustKhaithang you shouldn't have 127.*.*.* as the IP address of your DNS server. It doesn't make sense. Your machine cannot be its own DNS server. It's a valid question.

Comment: @Andy, I face the problem with Ubuntu 16.04 only and not with the other OS- having  the same connection and same network settings. The nameserver 127.0.0.53 is not doing it's job somehow.

Comment: @Andy it's the local nameserver used by systemd-resolve. the Systemd-resolves write that on the /etc/resolve.conf file.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328131/
All this means is that you need to look in another place for your real DNS settings.

Comment: @Andy Some of the those commands doesn't seem to work on mine but nevertheless I think I fairly had an idea on how to look or where to look. Thanks for the link.